# ATtiny85 AC Phase Control for dimming a light bulb

Tags: sensors, interrupt, timers, attiny, electronics

I'm trying to dim a light bulb via an ATtiny85, which accepts commands sent over I2C. My problem is that the bulb is barely dimming and is flickering quite a bit.

My circuit can be seen here:

[image: ATtiny85 dimming circuit controlled over I2C]

The opto-isolator (and thus the triac) is controlled via pin 2 (AKA PB3, AKA PCINT3) and AC zero cross detection is done on pin 3 (AKA PB4, AKA PCINT4) on the ATtiny85.

The code uses Pin Change Interrupt Enable rather than the single External Interrupt Enable, because the External Interrupt pin is pin 7 (aka PB2), which is used as the SCL for the I2C communication.

The 8MHz internal clock is used and the timer/counter prescaler is 1024, which means that I have an effective input range (see `level` variable in the code) of roughly 0-65. My AC source is USA (60Hz).

```c
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <TinyWireS.h>

#define PULSE 4       //trigger pulse width (counts)
#define I2C_SLAVE_ADDR 0x4 // the 7-bit address (remember to change this when adapting this example)

byte trigger = 3;
byte detector = 4;    
byte level = 50;
byte maxLevel = 65;
byte minLevel = 0;

void setup() {
    TinyWireS.begin(I2C_SLAVE_ADDR); // join i2c network
    TinyWireS.onRequest(requestEvent); //setup i2c requester
    digitalWrite(detector, HIGH);  //enable pull-up resistor
    pinMode(trigger, OUTPUT);// Set AC Load pin as output
    TCCR1 = 0;     //stop timer
    OCR1A = level;    //initialize the comparator
    TIMSK = _BV(OCIE1A) | _BV(TOIE1); //interrupt on Compare Match A and  enable timer overflow interrupt
    GIMSK = 0b00100000; //Enable pin change interrupt
    PCMSK = 0b00010000; //PB4, physical pin 3 PCINT4
    TCCR1 = B00001011; //Prescale the timer
    sei();  // Turn on interrupts
}

ISR(PCINT0_vect) {
    //interrupt looking for zero crossing
    TCNT1 = 0;   //reset timer - count from zero
    OCR1A = level;
    TCCR1 = B00001011;// prescaler on 1024, see table 12-5 of the tiny85 datasheet
}
ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect) {
    //comparator match
    digitalWrite(trigger,HIGH); //set triac gate to high
    TCNT1 = 255-PULSE;
    //trigger pulse width for a few cycles for triac to latch on. 255 bc the counter can only count up to 255
}

ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect) {
    //timer1 overflow
    digitalWrite(trigger, LOW); //turn off triac gate
    TCCR1 = 0;  //disable timer stop unintended triggers
}

void loop() {}

void requestEvent() {
    if (TinyWireS.available()) {
        level = TinyWireS.receive();
        if (level > maxLevel) {
            level = maxLevel;
         else if (level < minLevel){
            level = minLevel;
        }
    }
    TinyWireS.send(OCR1A);
}
```

I have tried a variety of bulbs (incandescent and dimmable LED), with none working any better than another.

Here is a video showing the zero cross detection (yellow) and the ATtiny85 trigger (blue) on an oscilloscope as I send it different dimming levels [Bad phone video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KnAW94fWrkg)

I've thought about the snubber, I just don't have the parts on hand right now. I think it will help but I don't think it will correct whatever my larger issue is.

I'd appreciate all and any help. Thanks.

(Note: I also posted this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41384498/attiny85-ac-phase-control-for-dimming-a-light-bulb). Apologies if crossposting is frowned upon).

Comment: Are you able to turn the bulb off? Maybe the signal needs to be inverted. The triac circuit looks very minimal to me, but I'm not that into triacs.

Comment: Sending the max level does turn it off... But I don't know if it actually doing it the way I want it to. 
Hmm What do you mean the signal needs to be inverted? 
I was inspired by [this](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/ACPhaseControl)

Comment: I meant a normally high signal with a short LOW pulse. So the blue trace upside down. But I'm just guessing here.

Comment: Are you sure about `47k` `R1` to the optotriac? Trigger current is `15mA` for the `MOC3021` and you have less than `0.1mA` (with `5V` power supply)

Comment: It's 0.47K. Poor picture quality . And using a 330ohm doesn't fix anything.

Comment: @thread9000 well, it should be about `220R` on `5V`. It's better to measure it.

Comment: Thanks @KIIV  but it still doesn't change the result. Any other thoughts?

Comment: This is really an electronics question not an Arduino one, especially as you are configuring the ATtiny hardware directly and not really going through the Arduino framework in more than the most trivial sense.  The snubber situation really can't be ignored.  Ultimately what you need to see is the behavior of the triac, but trying to measure that with a scope has too many dangerous pitfalls to recommend.  Are you sure you need to build this yourself?  It can be done, but it's not something to play with unless you really understand what is going on and how to do it safely.

Comment: @Gerben the circuit appears to be driving the Anode of the opto-triac device, so it would be an active high pulse to turn on the triac.   A typical dimmer like this achieves PWM by delaying some time after zero crossing before turning on the TRIAC, which will then remain on (regardless of input) until it shuts itself off at the next zero crossing.

Comment: Hi @ChrisStratton. The reason I am posting it here was to verify my code, which is very much using the Arduino API. Any electrical help and verification is a bonus, so I appreciate your input. 
I'm currently waiting on a triac with a built-in snubber to be delivered. 
I agree it would be nice to see out triac's output. I will reach out to an electrical engineer that I work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think there were (was?) two issues.

1) Pin change interrupts on the Attiny85 are triggered on rising and falling edges which I think was causing the flickering.

I changed the code to rising edge only triggering:

```
ISR(PCINT0_vect){ //interrupt looking for zero crossing
        if (digitalRead(4) == HIGH){
                TCNT1 = 0;   //reset timer - count from zero
                OCR1A = level;
                TCCR1 = B00001011;// prescaler on 1024, see table 12-5 of the tiny85 datasheet
       }
}
```

2) Attiny85 #reset pin. Pulled that guy high with a resistor.

Anyways, here's the oscilloscope and dimming led blub video: [youtube](https://youtu.be/0TM0iugDhyM)

Comment: Also, I switched to BTB08-600BWRG for the triac which helps with inductance (so far I've got five (65watt eq) LED light bulbs running just fine). (Note this didn't actually do anything the solve the original problem)